# google line chart for showing sales report hour wise

Tags: charts, google-visualization

how to draw google line chart for showing sales report hour wise, i searched in google and i found one solution for line chart, but in that it taken two items, but i need the line chart for sales per hour only..i tried by removing the second quantity but i am getting error . I tried with below code

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>     
</html>
<script>
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['linechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawCurveTypes);

function drawCurveTypes() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');

  data.addRows([
    [0, 0],    [1, 10],   [2, 23],  [3, 17 ],   [4, 18],  [5, 9],
    [6, 11],   [7, 27],  [8, 33],  [9, 40],  [10, 32], [11, 35,
    [12, 30], [13, 40], [14, 42], [15, 47], [16, 44], [17, 48],
    [18, 52], [19, 54], [20, 42]
  ]);

  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Popularity'
    },
    series: {
      1: {curveType: 'function'}
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```

when i tried with the above code i am getting the below errod 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) at the end of data.addRows. please some one help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the data...

there is a missing bracket on one of the array values...

```
data.addRows([
  [0, 0],    [1, 10],   [2, 23],  [3, 17 ],   [4, 18],  [5, 9],
  [6, 11],   [7, 27],  [8, 33],  [9, 40],  [10, 32], [11, 35,   // <-- missing bracket
  [12, 30], [13, 40], [14, 42], [15, 47], [16, 44], [17, 48],
  [18, 52], [19, 54], [20, 42]
]);
```

corrected...

```
data.addRows([
  [0, 0],    [1, 10],   [2, 23],  [3, 17 ],   [4, 18],  [5, 9],
  [6, 11],   [7, 27],  [8, 33],  [9, 40],  [10, 32], [11, 35],   // <-- correct
  [12, 30], [13, 40], [14, 42], [15, 47], [16, 44], [17, 48],
  [18, 52], [19, 54], [20, 42]
]);
```

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawCurveTypes);

function drawCurveTypes() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');

  data.addRows([
    [0, 0],    [1, 10],   [2, 23],  [3, 17 ],   [4, 18],  [5, 9],
    [6, 11],   [7, 27],  [8, 33],  [9, 40],  [10, 32], [11, 35],
    [12, 30], [13, 40], [14, 42], [15, 47], [16, 44], [17, 48],
    [18, 52], [19, 54], [20, 42]
  ]);

  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Popularity'
    },
    series: {
      1: {curveType: 'function'}
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

*note:* only need `'corechart'` package...

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
```